# Orbital Velocity Of An Object

Tags: newtonian-gravity, centripetal-force

So by equating the gravitational force and the centripetal acceleration of an object the is assumed to revolve around a certain planet we have found the formula for a velocity called Orbital velocity.

Now this velocity is the velocity required by an object to move the object all the way from the surface of the planet to the respective planet's orbit and then make it revolve around it RIGHT!!! .

So my question is, is this the velocity we want the object to attain when it is at the orbit because then, propelling the object with orbital velocity from surface of the planet will obviously slow the speed(due to constant gravitational pull of the planet) and thus when the object reaches the orbit it's speed is very less than orbital velocity, then how will it maintain the circular motion. And if the above is not true then it means we are really releasing the object with orbital velocity from the surface of the planet it self, then what is the speed of the object when it revolves around the planet?

Bit confused with this question ,any help will be useful.

Comment: I suggest you take some time to edit this and phrase your question carefully. It's convoluted.

Comment: Also see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vis-viva_equation & https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_velocity & https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virial_theorem

Answer (score 2):

The speed you calculate by equating the gravitational force $\dfrac{GMm}{r^2}$ and the centripetal force $\dfrac{mv^2}{r}$ gives you the speed the object $m$ must have while in orbit.

If you want to find the speed needed on earth to launch an object to such an orbit, then you can use conservation of energy. However, this is a bit more complicated, since you'll need to ensure that the object changes directions too (otherwise it won't enter the desired orbit).

Comment: Sexy answer sir,I was thinking the same way,but to get it from some one like yourself,gives s sense of confidence to me